# Why is T5 often used in text-to-data for text prompt encoders?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer, embeddings, generative-models

In the text-to-data(music, image, audio, etc.) generative AI field, one method of encoding text prompts is to use pre-trained language models. Such an approach was used in research on Moûsai [1] and Photorealistic [2] , for example. And in such recent text-to-data generative AI fields, T5 is often used for this pre-trained language model.

But why is T5 often used?

I also wonder if LLMs with a larger number of parameters than T5 could be used to better represent the complexity and composition of music. Therefore, I do not understand why such LLMs are not used.

### References:

[1] Schneider, et al., ‘Moûsai: Text-to-Music Generation with Long-Context Latent Diffusion’, Available: https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.11757

[2] Saharia et al., 'Photorealistic Text-to-Image Diffusion Models with Deep Language Understanding', Available: https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike many of the other LLMs, T5 is an encoder-decoder model.  (Most are encoder-only like BERT, or decoder-only like the GPT models.)

So it is well suited to sequence to sequence applications.
The 11B model is also far from being a small model. Running anything bigger is going to require some serious hardware resources.